# Как правильно записать словарь в файл?

Tags: python, csv, beautiful-soup, словари, файловый-ввод-вывод

Код:

```
    for tr_time in trs:     
        time_game = tr_time.find('td', class_='first time')
        if time_game:
            clear_time_game = time_game.text[:5]
            # print(clear_time_game)
            
            data.append = {'clear_time_game': clear_time_game,
                           '2': 2,
                           '1': 1}




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Собирается много данных, но в файл записывается только последняя запись, почему?
Возможно переменные, которые хранят данные постоянно переопределяются, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы перезаписываете данные в `data`, в итоге там - последнее значение...

```
data = {'clear_time_game': clear_time_game,
            'name': name,
            'url_players': url_players}
```

Сместите write_csv(data) в тело цикла, должно получиться как-то так:

```
for tr_time in trs:     
        time_game = tr_time.find('td', class_='first time')
        if time_game:
            clear_time_game = time_game.text[:5]
            print(clear_time_game)

            data = {
                'clear_time_game': clear_time_game
                'name': name,
                'url_players': url_players}
            
            write_csv(data)
```

Comment: А как исправить "Возникло исключение: AttributeError
'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only " Наверно мне стоит создать новый цикл именно для записи данных в словарь?

Comment: @dog3000 в каком месте?

Comment: После последнего цикла, который забирает время (clear_time_game = time_game.text[:5]) вставил на локальном уровне. Создал список data = [], и ниже без отступов разместил код append

Comment: @dog3000 дополнил, перепроверьте, что и где вы аппендите

Comment: Сделал по примеру, обновил код выше. Снова возникло исключение: AttributeError 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119558/discussion-between-jack-os-and-dog3000).